# How many dimensions our universe consists of?

Tags: string-theory, universe, spacetime-dimensions

Omnibus science convinces us in that we live within three-dimensional space.
The coordinate measuring units XYZ.

Quite controversial, but there are some legitimate theories clarifying why we live in four-dimensional space instead.
And there was a theory that says 5.

As a matter of fact,
neither of these theories attracted me except for the rare one claiming that we live in INFINITE dimensions and it is a matter of interpretation.
X * Y = Z(1)
X * Y * Z(1) * L ...
The visual interpretation becomes more complex, but it exists.
I mean only the dimensions related to area are measurable, it is about the exponential growth and that the next (4th dimensional) coordinate would be just more distant.

---

Why would we exist in only 3 dimensional space?

Comment: What does that equation mean?

Answer (score 1):

3 dimentions of space and 1 dimention of time,which are the macro-dimentions of our universe.

some higher dimentions in some kind of physical models are mathematical tricks more than their physical meanings，such like 5-dimentions（4 of space and 1 of time） for the unifying of electromagnetic force and gravity.

Comment: If "time" is considered a valid dimension then it is passable on arbitrary axis. Otherwise it isn't really part of the coordinate system.

Comment: of course time is

Comment: in classical mechanics, you could think our universe as R×R^3, wherein R is time and R^3 is space. in this picture, there exists no relation between time and space. but in relativity, you cannot think time as an independent part of coordinate system

Comment: I don't see the relation between time and the xyz and how they affect each other. If time is a 4th dimension then we can travel through it by xyz reduction or pre-circulation.

Answer (score 0):

Out of four fundamental forses except gravitation all other three forces are comparable but gravity is very less, this can be explained if graviry is consentrated somewere else . The main idea is that our 3Dimensional universe is just projection of heigher dimensons , it is same as we project 3D object on 2D surface we will get different projection on diffrent surface dependind on there position. Similarly week gravity can be explained on basis of this, if projection of gravity in our universe is more distorted as compared to other forces. It means that strength of forces will be diffrent in diffrent universe.
Moreover expansion of Universe due to Dark Matter can be explained by the concept of extra dimensons.
Physicist have different views on numbed of dimensions, some are saying 9 and some are also saying only 1. It is complitly mysterious topic now.